# WPF UserControl: Client-side validation of TargetType for custom styles?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, user-controls

I have a `UserControl` for multi-purpose use.
For the sake of simplicity, I'll show you the control first:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CompetitionAgent.View.UserControls.ExpandingButtonGrid"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="200" d:DesignHeight="200"
             Margin="0" Padding="0" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" >
    <StackPanel Name="stpBody" Style="{Binding Style}">
        <Button x:Name="btnExpander" Content="{Binding ExpanderButtonText}"
                Style="{Binding ExpandButtonStyle}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="btnExpander_Click"
                Height="25" Width="Auto" />
        <StackPanel x:Name="stpButtons" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    Style="{Binding PanelStyle}"
                    Margin="0">
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Controls `stpBody`, `stpButtons` and `btnExpander` all have styles bound by the `DataContext`. The fields look like this:

```
#region body styles
public Style Style { get; set; }
public Style ExpandButtonStyle { get; set; }
#endregion body styles

#region button pannel styles
public Style PanelStyle { get; set; }
public Style ButtonStyle { get; set; }
#endregion button pannel styles
```

So when this `UserControl` is used in another window, it would look somewhat like this:

```
<UserControls:ExpandingButtonGrid x:Name="ebgSchemeManager" 
                                  Style="{StaticResource ExpandingButtonGridStyle}" 
                                  PanelStyle="{StaticResource ExpandingButtonGridPanelStyle}" 
                                  ExpandButtonStyle="{StaticResource ExpandingButtonGridExpandButtonStyle}" />
```

I was wondering, is there a way to validate the `TargetTypes` of the `StaticResource` styles so that they are required to target a stackpanel or button respectively?

For example, style `ExpandingButtonGridExpandButtonStyle` could target a `DockPanel`, resulting in a XAML parse exception at runtime.

**UPDATE - Summary and update on Depency Objects**

I've just figured out what `DepencyObjects` are (hurray!).
For those who are wondering, you need to register the field so the property can be assigned to dynamically.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ExpandButtonStyleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ExpandButtonStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(ExpandingButtonPanel));

public Style ExpandButtonStyle
{
    get
    {
        return (Style)GetValue(ExpandButtonStyleProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        if (!typeof(Button).IsAssignableFrom(value.TargetType))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The target type is expected to be button");
        }
        SetValue(ExpandButtonStyleProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can validate which style was set and throw exception (will be instantly visible in designer when you try to do so). For this `Style`/`PanelStyle`/etc. has to be *dependency properties*.

Comment: @Sinatr Coincidentally I just received this error `A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.` I'll have to look into that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is. You can verify the [`Style.TargetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.style.targettype(v=vs.110).aspx) in your setter. This will also be checked by the WPF Designer.

For example:

```
private Style _buttonStyle;
public Style ButtonStyle 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return _buttonStyle;
    }
    set 
    { 
        if (!typeof(Button).IsAssignableFrom(value.TargetType))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The target type is expected to be Button");
        } 
        _buttonStyle = value;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks, I'll try your solution right away to verify. Thanks!

Comment: If there are any errors in the C# syntax… please tell me. I usually use VB.net but I'd like to fix the answer if required.

Comment: It works, but you forget the semi-colon `return _buttonStyle;` and the semi-colon after the closing bracket of the setter shouldn't be there `_buttonStyle = value;
    }`. Understandable if you're used to VB.net ;)